# php doesnt load my css even thought route is correct

Tags: php

So im trying to make my first php app, and the problem i am facing that php file isnt loading any of the css in console when page loads i get

```
GET http://localhost/PHP-CATALOG/public/assets/catalog/css/bootstrap.min.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

the route is correct but i dont understand why i get not found?

config

```
    /* ROOT PATHS */
$path = str_replace("\\", "/","http://" . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . __DIR__  . "/");
$path = str_replace($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'], "", $path);

define('ROOT', str_replace("app/core", "public", $path));
define('ASSETS', str_replace("app/core", "public/assets", $path));
```

linking css in index.php page

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?=ASSETS?>catalog/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?=ASSETS?>catalog/css/all.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?=ASSETS?>catalog/templatemo-style.css">
```

tried hitting f5 + ctrl refresh using other browser in case it was cache issue, but nope nothing works.

Comment: do you still get a 404 if you just open `http://localhost/PHP-CATALOG/public/assets/catalog/css/bootstrap.min.css` in browser?

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem.
It was because i changed the port on xampp from 80 to 88

Solution:

```
$path = str_replace("\\", "/","http://" . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']. ":88". __DIR__  . "/");
```